# populate ListView from Another class Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to populate a ListView from Another class which run on another thread but I failed to do that.
Here is the main Activity :

```
public ListView myList;
List < string>contacts = new List< string>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Control);
        myList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.contactsList);
        myList.ItemLongClick += MyList_ItemLongClick;
    }

    public void insertContact(string ContactInfo)
    {
        myList=FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.contactsList);
        contacts.Add(ContactInfo);
        ArrayAdapter<string> myArray = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Application.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, contacts);
        list.Adapter = null;
        list.Adapter = myArray;
        myList.DeferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void startAsync(){
        Contacts con = new Contacts();
        Thread thread = new Thread(()=> con.Start());
        thread.Start();
    }
```

I'm firing a method from another class to grap contacts.
There it just get some info and should send it to main Activity
The other class doing like

```
MainAct main = new MainAct();
main.insertContact("new Contact");
```

but It did nothing.
I tried to make a method to get the listView from the main activity (like mentioned in some thread) and pass it as second paramter to add contact like :

```
public ListView getListView()
        {
            ListView myList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.contactsList);
            return myList;
        }
```

and after than calling this line which has the ListView :

```
main.insertContact("new Contact", main.getListView());
```

but I got an exception :

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: < Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

I tried from the other class to run the line like :

```
main.RunOnUIThread(()=>     main.insertContact("new Contact", main.getListView()));
```

but got the same exception !
What did I missed ?

**NOTE:** If I put both classes in one class ( I mean all the code in one class ) It works without a problem with RunOnUIThread(()=> ); . but When I move the method to another class, I got the exception.

**EDIT 1:**
When I catch the exception I got nullpointer

```
Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
```

Comment: By `populate a ListView from Another class`, do you want to use MVC in your project? And by `I'm firing a method from another class to grap contacts.` can you show the codes?

Comment: Does the `Contacts` class is your `another class`?

Comment: I have put my demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewPopulate) for you to try it.

Comment: Hello, have you tested my demo? If there is any question about my demo, please feel free to ask me.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code was wrong written here, In this code : 
public void startAsync(){
        Contacts con = new Contacts();
        Thread thread = new Thread(()=> con.Start());
        thread.Start();
    }
I meant to write 
public void startAsync(){
        MainAct con = new MainAct();
        Thread thread = new Thread(()=> con.Start());
        thread.Start();
    }
Here I call a method from other class, and the other class should call insertContact to send data back to listview in the first class. I'll edit the code. Sorry for that. And no, I don't want to use MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If `Contacts` is your another class, I suggest you rename it as `MyContacts`, because there is a [Contacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) class,it will confused us.

2) You don't need to new `MainAct`, just pass the context to your another class.

---

I have tried to reproduce your question, and I add a comment for these codes:

Here is your `MyContacts` class:

```
   public class MyContacts
    {
        MainActivity mContext;
        public MyContacts(MainActivity context) {
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        public void Start() {
            mContext.insertContact("new Contact");

            mContext.insertContact("new Contact1");

            mContext.insertContact("new Contact2");
        }
    }
```

You `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public ListView myList;
    List<string> contacts = new List<string>();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        myList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.contactsList);

        //we usually init the data in OnCreate method.
        startAsync();


    }
    public void insertContact(string ContactInfo)
    {
        //this is redundant, because you have Instantiated the myList in the OnCreate method.
        //myList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.contactsList);
        contacts.Add(ContactInfo);

        //You can use this instead of Application.Context.
        ArrayAdapter<string> myArray = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, contacts);

        myList.Adapter = myArray;

        //from your question, I can't find any information about the list property.
        //list.Adapter = null;
        //list.Adapter = myArray;

        //myList.DeferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //From your question, I can't find where have you call this method, I will call it in the OnCreate method
    public void startAsync()
    {
        MyContacts con = new MyContacts(this);
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => con.Start());
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try the code and come back with results thank you

Comment: unfortunately I got the same exception in line : contacts.Add(ContactInfo); which is in the main activity. I tried to add con.RunOnUIThread() in the class where I call method insertContact, the exception disappeared but nothing showed in ListView. What did I miss ? This driving me crazy !

Comment: Ok my fault sorry. ArrayAdapter was in OnCreate method and that's why I got nothing in my listview. Now After adding con.RunOnUIThread(()=> con.insertContact("new Contact"));  since it's running on another thread, it's working. I have learned a valuable lesson thanks a lot Joe.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to find " Accept it as answer " from yesterday but I found nothing, and that's why I up voted ur answer ! Sorry I'm new to this forum !! Where to find that button to click on ?